# Powershell removing escape chars on conversion

Tags: json, regex, powershell

I have some automatically generated json files I need to modify using PowerShell. However, when I use the `ConvertFrom-Json` I'm in some cases losing chars.

I tried using

```bsh
ForEach-Object {
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_)
}
```

To handle the unescape chars, but no luck

The example of a string getting modified

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?><ExchangeRates>
```

is getting transformed to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><ExchangeRates>
```

Losing the backslashes.

How would I getting around this without transforming the unintentional parts of the file ?

Comment: Do not use `Regex.Unescape` in the first place.  What do you need to do?

Comment: Can you show us a complete sample json string with which this behavior occur?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen
The xml line is part of a json example file im testing this with.    
  ```"Compose": {
                  "runAfter": {
                    "Transform_Exchange_Rates": [
                      "Succeeded"
                    ]
                  },
                  "type": "Compose",
                  "inputs": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?><ExchangeRates>"
                },
```

Comment: In that case I'm not quite sure I understand your question - PowerShell correctly decodes a literal string value in the json file. `ConvertTo-Json` would (also correctly) add the escape sequence again

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
I need to load in the file as a json object, and then I'm correcting some parameters in other parts of the file. However this file contains some of the above examples and I know more files containing this type of lines

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen
Not in this case apparently. As soon as I have converted it to a PowerShell json object, the backslashes is gone, and not coming back when converted back to json

Comment: For me `$(Get-Content "C:\temp\test.txt") | Convertfrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Compress` gives : `{"Compose":{"runAfter":{"Transform_Exchange_Rates":"Succeeded"},"type":"Compose","inputs":"\u003c?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?\u003e\u003cExchangeRates\u003e"}}`. It seems Ok.

Answer (score 0):

I redid the testing in a clean environment, and found out I had something that enforced a UTF8 encoding when I loaded the content into a son object in PowerShell which in this case causes the chars to be converted into escape chars which results in them being replaced by nothing in my case

tldr; UTF8 formatting when doing the convertfrom-json was causing the problem